# Linear dependence of multivariable functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

It is well known that the Wronskian is a great tool for checking the linear dependence between a set of functions of one variable.

Is there a similar way of checking linear dependance between two functions of two variables (e.g. $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$)?

Thanks.

Comment: $W=P(x,y)\cdot\nabla{Q(x,y)}-Q(x,y)\cdot\nabla{P(x,y)}$ appears to work upon inspection of a few cases...but I don't want to say for sure that it works in all cases.

Comment: @Panda I disagree. The Wronskian is good for checking linear independence of sets of functions. On the other hand, there are well-known examples where the Wronskian is identically zero for linearly independent sets of functions. In the context of solution sets to linear systems of DEqns we have the nice results, but generally, be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian and in particular the section "Generalized Wronskian".

Comment: I think there is also a way of phrasing the question in terms of wedge products of differentials of the functions in question.

Answer (score 0):

For checking linear dependency between two functions of two variables we can follow the follwing theorem given by "Green, G. M., Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., New York, 17, 1916,(483-516)".

**Theorem:** Let $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ be functions of two independence variables $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ i.e., $y_{1} = y_{1}(x_{1} ,x_{2}) $ and $y_{2} = y_{1}(x_{1} ,x_{2}) $ for which all partial derivatives of $1^{st}$ order, $\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{k}}$, $\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{k}}$, $(k = 1,2)$ exists throughout the region $A$. Suppose, farther, that one of the functions, say $y_{1}$, vanishes at no point of $A$. Then if *all the two rowed determinants in the matrix* 
\begin{pmatrix} 
y_{1} & y_{2} \\
\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{1}} \\
\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
vanish identically in $A$, $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are linearly dependent in $A$, and in fact $y_{2}=c y_{1}$.